# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, fs

When I try to import the fs module in my own module like `import * as fs from 'fs'` the following error in the browser console comes:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`.

Using `require` or using a relative path to the module like `./node_modules/fs` will not work, is there any other way of importing the fs module correctly?

Comment: You may refer to [node-imports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#node-imports) doc.

Comment: Can you please provide more info? Like which framework are you working with? Is it ReactJS? or is it NodeJS (express)?

Comment: @subodhkalika I am using Node.js with vanilla Javascript.

Comment: I don"t think that package can be made to work in the browser.

Comment: @piffels — If you are using Node.js, why are you looking at the browser console? The browser console only matters if you are using a browser and not Node.js

Comment: @Quentin I am using a browser, because I am trying to create a website while using the Live Server extension in VSCode to open my HTML file

Comment: @piffels — My point was that you are **not using Node.js**

Comment: @Quentin I apologize, I got confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two basic problems, both of which stem from the fact you are running this code in a browser and not in Node.js.

---

Passing something like `'fs'` to `import` depends on Node.js style module resolution. Node.js will search the contents of  the `node_modules` folder for matching modules. Browsers can't do that, they haven't got a file system to search; they only deal in URLs.

When dealing with modules in a browser you have to pass either:

- A URL that includes an absolute path (like `/fs` or `http://example.com/fs`)
- A URL that is an explicitly relative path (like `../fs` or `./fs`).

… just like the error message says.

(Typically you'll also need to put a `.js` on the end of the URL because your HTTP server is unlikely to do that for you).

---

You also need to use a module which will run in a browser in the first place.

`fs` is a Node.js built-in module. It does things which browsers **do not** allow JavaScript to do (like access the file system).

If you want to use the `fs` module then you can't use it directly from the browser. Instead, write a web service in Node.js (the Express.js module is useful here) and access it from the browser using Ajax (e.g. the `fetch` API). This will deal with the server's file system, not the browser's.

If you want to access files on the user's computer, then you'll need to use `<input type="file">` and the `FileReader` API.