# DXF parser in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, parsing, npm, dxf

I am currently working on a CNC project, I want to be able to parse DXF files into objects in JS.
I started with SVGs instead but the drawings did not export as shapes but as lines (a square as four lines and not a shape with four points). So I began to search for a JS library that would help me work with DXF files, I found "dxf-parser" and "three-dxf". I wasn't able to run an example with neither... That might be because I have a very limited experience with vanilla JS , I usually use P5.

So, in conclusion, I am searching for a working example projects of any of these libraries.

What I did by now was to write in the command line:

```
npm init -y
npm i dxf parser
```

Then I opened an html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
</script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And a JS file:

```
// Grab fileText in node.js or browser
import parse from 'dxf-parser';

const fileText = "./dxfTests/test.dxf";

try {
    const dxf = parse(fileText);
}catch(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
}
```

Then I start click the go live button in VScode and i get this error:

```
127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "dxf-parser". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is this typo or you really have ghost closing script tag? `<head></script>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing a package in ES6: "Failed to resolve module specifier "vue""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612446/importing-a-package-in-es6-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-vue)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72458428/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-fs-relative-references)

Comment: `npm i dxf-parser` with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `import parse from 'dxf-parser';` to `import parse from './dxf-parser.js';`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).